# SQL Server hangs on PREEMPTIVE_OS_AUTHZINITIALIZECON?

Tags: sql-server

One of my production machines (SQL Server Express 2012) has not been performing too well. I started running the WhoIsActive script and I've been getting a lot of these wait types:

(10871ms)PREEMPTIVE_OS_AUTHZINITIALIZECON

They always occur when calling a function that checks certain user privileges. If I understand this correctly, the function had to wait almost 11 seconds for the Windows function AuthzInitializeContextFromSid (see https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/preemptive_os_authzinitializecontextfromsid/).

1. Am I correct in my assumption? (full output below)
2. I couldn't find any info online about this wait type going hayrwire. What could be causing this?

Full output:

```
00 00:00:10.876 75  
<?query --
select  @RetValue = ([dbo].[Users_IsMember]('some_role_name', @windowsUserName)
                             | is_srvrolemember('SysAdmin', @windowsUserName))
--?>

<?query --
MyDB.dbo.StoredProcName;1
--?>

DOMAIN\User (10871ms)PREEMPTIVE_OS_AUTHZINITIALIZECON   master: 0 (0 kB),tempdb: 0 (0 kB),MyDB: 0 (0 kB)                 10,875                   0                   0 NULL                     93                   0                   0 <ShowPlanXML xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan" Version="1.5" Build="11.0.7001.0"><BatchSequence><Batch><Statements><StmtSimple StatementText="select  @RetValue = ([dbo].[Users_IsMember]('some_role_name', @windowsUserName)&#xD;&#xA;                             | is_srvrolemember('SysAdmin', @windowsUserName))&#xD;&#xA;       " StatementId="1" StatementCompId="49" StatementType="ASSIGN WITH QUERY" RetrievedFromCache="true" /></Statements></Batch></BatchSequence></ShowPlanXML>                      3 runnable    NULL                      0 NULL    ServerName  AppName .Net SqlClient Data Provider    2018-12-17 09:29:35.413 2018-12-17 09:29:35.413 0   2018-12-17 09:29:46.447
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the PREEMPTIVE_OS wait stats are related to an imbalance between how much memory is allocated to SQL Server vs. the Windows OS itself.

In this case, the OS is being starved for memory resources. You might try either adding more total memory to the box, or ensuring that SQL Server is configured to only use 80 percent of the total memory installed on the instance. Or both.

- Note - this is not a blanket statement on how to configure memory for SQL server, but rather a good place to start with tuning for PREEMPTIVE_OS related wait types.